# How to use the after() method in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So here is this code, this is a clock or something, basically i understand it. The question is: Does it matter that i write before the .after(...) I mean i could write there any widget that is in the window, or the window itself, even though it makes no sense to use that widget, but it would work i guess. I know that the method does.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *

def update():
    time_string = strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    time_label.config(text=time_string)

    day_string = strftime("%A")
    day_label.config(text=day_string)

    date_string = strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    date_label.config(text=date_string)

    window.after(1000,update)   <-----------------------------------------------------


window = Tk()

time_label = Label(window,font=("Arial",50),fg="#00FF00",bg="black")
time_label.pack()

day_label = Label(window,font=("Ink Free",25,"bold"))
day_label.pack()

date_label = Label(window,font=("Ink Free",30))
date_label.pack()

update()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The question is: Does it matter that i write before the .after(...) I mean i could write there any widget that is in the window, or the window itself, even though it makes no sense to use that widget, but it would work i guess." I have absolutely no idea what this sentence is supposed to mean. Please slow down and try to organize your thoughts more clearly. It sounds like you are asking about other ways to write the code. Did you **try** other ways to write the code? *Did they appear to work*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after` method can be called from any widget. The method behaves exactly the same no matter which widget you use.